# Dynamic Detection of Hand Movement using Accelerometer

Tags: android, accelerometer

I want to detect the movement of the hand dynamically and modify sound accordingly. The phone is in the hand in a fixed orientation which does not change. For Example, I am holding the phone in my stretched hand and as it moves to the right or left, my music volume changes dynamically; If I move up and down the speed of playing changes and moving at some intermediate angle changes both speed and volume accordingly. I charted the accelerometer data while doing these motions and there seems to be some pattern but I am not sure how to filter those. I have looked at a lot of posts - High Pass/Low Pass filters, Kalman Filters, Gesture Recognizers but it is difficult to understand what is the appropriate method. Most of the posts don't seem to detect dynamically - but only when a certain gesture is finished. I only need to use accelerometer and not gyroscope and any other sensor. What is the correct approach here? Are there any existing libraries that do this?

Answer (score 0):

if your activity implements

```
SensorEventListener
```

and you use the variables

```
private SensorManager sensorManager;
private Sensor mAccelerometer;
```

in your OnCreate() you instantiate them and register the listener like this:

```
sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
mAccelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
sensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
```

and then use this method to get the accelerometer data

```
 public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        double x = event.values[0];
        double y = event.values[1];
        double z = event.values[2];
}
```

and you can take it from there depending on the values you get from the accelerometer, make the changes to the volume or whatever

Comment: On top of that, you'll have to apply a bandpass filter on the sensor data, compute resultant vectors from the three axes and determine the direction of motion. You should go for Kalman filter if you want precise pose estimation, else just a filter applied on the x,y,z reading should suffice.

Comment: Thanks! Could you elaborate a bit - why I would need the bandpass filter - it seems that low pass will eliminate the smaller changes (noise) and leave me with a smooth trend.

Comment: you might want to check this link, i dont know much about filtering, i started looking at it because im thinking i read the question wrong, i thought you just get the data and go from there, i never heard of filtering, http://www.researchgate.net/post/Using_a_Kalman_filter_to_filter_noise_out_of_accelerometer_data

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html, you should be able to definetly figure it out if you can understand this